# Font sizes on question preview and the question page don't match.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When composing a message, the font is like this

[image: composing]

But on the posted question it is like this:

[image: question page]

Comment: @Caramadir the fix will be in tonight. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this, it will be in the next deployment.